# Invoke function in object literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I include a `function` call in my destructuring, `TrimText` removes html from a string.

```
data.map(item => {
  const {
    id,
    title: { rendered: title },
    content: { rendered: description },
    youtubeVideo
  } = item;


  const newVideo = {
    id,
    trimText(title), // removes html from title and description
      trimText(description),
    youtubeVideo
  };

  videos.push(newVideo);
});
```

The above gives me a syntax error, missing {}

Comment: You're not destructuring here, you're creating an object literate.

Comment: `{id}` is just shorthand for `{id: id}`.

Answer (score 1):

The properties `id` and youtubeVideo will work fine but for `trimText(title)` and `trimText(description)` because they are expressions. You need to put `key:value` in objects.

```
data.map(item => {
  const {
    id,
    title: { rendered: title },
    content: { rendered: description },
    youtubeVideo
  } = item;


  const newVideo = {
    id,
    title:trimText(title), // removes html from title and description
    description:trimText(description),
    youtubeVideo
  };

  videos.push(newVideo);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As zero298 mentions in the comments `{ title }` is short for `{ title: title }`. But if you're doing some processing on the value you need to explicitly assign the value returned from that function to a property key:

```
title: trimText(title)
```

Another issue with your code is you're using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which returns a new array, while also `push`ing new data into an array called `videos`, so you either need to use one method or the other:

#### Mutating the `videos` array with `forEach`:

```
const videos = [];
data.forEach(el => {

  // create a new data object
  const newData = { ...blah };
  videos.push(newData);
});
```

#### Iterating over the data with `map`, which returns a new array and and assigns it to `videos`

```
const videos = data.map(el => {  

  // create a new data object
  const newData = { ...blah };
  return newData;
});
```